# Gaussian Elimination SPD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show that no pivoting is necessary during Gaussian elimination 
of a symmetric positive definite matrix?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer should be based on Cholesky factorization of SPD.
Since this is the case by forward backward substitution we get the result.
So no need to pivoting.